# Как добавить стиль к тексту?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как добавить стиль `css('text-decoration', 'line-through')` к `label` при включенном чекбоксе?

```
<input id="checkallow" type="checkbox">
<label for="checkallow">Отправляя сообщение, я подтверждаю ...</label>
<button class="checkallow" type="submit" disabled=""> Отправить </button>

$('#checkallow').on('change', function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')) $('.checkallow').attr('disabled', false); 
else $('.checkallow').attr('disabled', true);  
});
```

https://codepen.io/stopani/pen/bLydyR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя селектор по значению атрибута https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

```
    $('#checkallow').on('change', function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.checkallow').attr('disabled', false);
        $('[for="checkallow"]').css('text-decoration', 'line-through'); // добавляем
      } else {
        $('.checkallow').attr('disabled', true); 
        $('[for="checkallow"]').css('text-decoration', ''); // удаляем
      }
    });
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pamjjK